# Flutter StreamProvider returning null despite stream returning objects

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies, flutter-provider

I'm try to set up a profile type page where users can view their information and eventually I'll add features so they can change their data. I'm using Provider to access a Firebase stream `<User>` which returns the current user's UID (this is working fine). The UID is then used to access their `<UserData>` stream, but when I try and print `UserData().email` or any other bits of data it just returns null. The code is as follows:

```
class Profile extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _ProfileState createState() => _ProfileState();
}

class _ProfileState extends State<Profile> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    final user = Provider.of<User>(context);

    return StreamProvider<UserData>.value(
      initialData: UserData.initialData(),
      value: DatabaseService(uid: user.uid).userData,
      child: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(),
        drawer: NavigationDrawer(),
        body: ListView(
          children: <Widget>[
            ListTile(
              title: Text(UserData().email),
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

The stream itself looks like this:

```
  UserData _userDataFromSnapshot(DocumentSnapshot snapshot) {
    return UserData(
      uid: uid,
      email: snapshot.data['email'],
      firstName: snapshot.data['firstName'],
      lastName: snapshot.data['lastName'],
      phone: snapshot.data['phone'],
      dateCreated: snapshot.data['dataCreated'],
      isVerified: snapshot.data['isVerified']
    );
  }

  //User data stream
  Stream<UserData> get userData {
    return userDataCollection.document(uid).snapshots()
        .map(_userDataFromSnapshot);
  }
```

And the UserData class is just this

```
class UserData {

  final String uid;
  final String email;
  final String firstName;
  final String lastName;
  final String phone;
  final DateTime dateCreated;
  final bool isVerified;

  UserData({ this.uid, this.email, this.firstName, this.lastName, this.phone, this.dateCreated, this.isVerified });

  factory UserData.initialData() {
    return UserData(
      uid: '',
      email: '',
      firstName: '',
      lastName: '',
      phone: '',
      dateCreated: null,
      isVerified: null,
    );
  }
}
```

And finally this is the error I'm getting from the ListTile because `UserData().email` is null, not a string:

```
A non-null String must be provided to a Text widget.
'package:flutter/src/widgets/text.dart':
Failed assertion: line 285 pos 10: 'data != null'
```

I thought it may have been an issue with the data not loading in time so when Flutter tries to build the page the data isn't there, but adding the `UserData.initialData` didn't seem to help. I have managed to get it working using StreamBuilder instead however I don't whether using that is best practice or if I should just do everything with Provider so any help wold be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you have used the StreamProvider wrong way. In the following code you are creating a new UserData object.

```
   ListTile(
          title: Text(UserData().email),
        )
```

Here is aa example how you can use the StreamProvider by creating a separate Widget.

```
class Profile extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _ProfileState createState() => _ProfileState();
}

class _ProfileState extends State<Profile> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    return StreamProvider<UserData>.value(
      initialData: UserData.initialData(),
      value: DatabaseService(uid: user.uid).userData,
      child: SecondWidget(),
    );
  }
}

class SecondWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final user = Provider.of<UserData>(context);
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(),
      drawer: NavigationDrawer(),
      body: ListView(
        children: <Widget>[
          ListTile(
            title: Text(user.email),
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks very much, that works great, though I just kept the `final user = Provider.of<User>(context);` bit in `_ProfileState` as that provides the uid needed in the `DatabaseService(uid: user.uid)`